# split pandas dataframe into two based on day of the week

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, pandas, anaconda

I have a data frame that looks like the image below:

[image]

the data frame is called `df_original`.

How do I split it so that I end up with a `df_weekend` which contains all the data that occurs on Saturday and Sundar, and `df_weekday` which contains all the data from Monday to Friday?

I originally tried using the solution found at [Pandas - Split dataframe into multiple dataframes based on dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907421/pandas-split-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes-based-on-dates)

But I ran into a `ValueError`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas - Split dataframe into multiple dataframes based on dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907421/pandas-split-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes-based-on-dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use boolean indexing:

```
mask = df_original['day'].isin(['Saturday','Sunday'])

df_weekend = df_original[mask]
df_weekday = df_original[~mask]
```

Comment: When I try that I get the error `raise ValueError('Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only')

ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only`